# How to Include html file inside another in yeoman?

Tags: yeoman, yeoman-generator

Is there way in Yeoman to include static html file inside another one? 
(`<%= yield %>` is the analog in middleman)

I have several index/list pages that use the same html code (

> header.html, footer.html, nav.html

, etc...)

Cheers

Comment: yes use partials http://www.fettblog.eu/blog/2013/09/02/using-assemble-io-with-yeoman-ios-webapp-gruntfile/

Comment: You're looking for a solution simply using Yeoman on your project - or to use inside your own generator?

Comment: @SamD thanks! Didnt have a chance to set this up yet...

Comment: @SimonBoudrias Yep, just in Yeoman

Comment: @tokmak Then look for a solution related to the server template engine you use in production - this is not directly related to Yeoman.